# Retaining special characters like é

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have some strings like `Café` that contains special characters such as `é`. However I get problems like PHP is turning them into other characters like `Ã©`. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: what are you doing to the strings?

Comment: I'm grabbing them from a website via `get_file_contents()` then saving a image file with that name. I suspect the characters are causing me problem with increasing the CPU load

Comment: @Pekka - +1 for a good read. :)

Comment: you need to add more information. What character set does the remote web site serve its data in? What character set does your web site serve its data in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the [character encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) that you are using.

Comment: @iOSprogrammer — A real HTTP header is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

?